# My rect isn't updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have used pygame for a while now, but now the player rect isn't updating or noticing collisions. It is still moving though. This just happened  after I modified a bit of code. I have looked at the .draw functions and the walls and the border is being drawn, but the player isn't, and the screen is being updated. (The code snippet is in javascript because I still don't know how to use a code snippet in python.)

```js
import pygame, sys, random
from pygame.locals import *
from time import sleep
pygame.init()

def render():
    windowSurface.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface,white,player1)
    if level == 1:
        pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface,white,wall_lvl_1_1)
        pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface,white,wall_lvl_1_2)
        pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface,white,border1_lvl_1)
    elif level == 2:
        filler = 'done'
    pygame.display.update()
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
windowSurface = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500),0,32)
windowSurface.fill(black)
level = 1
xmod = 0
ymod = 0
direction = 'none'
player1 = pygame.Rect(225 + xmod,450 - ymod,30,30)
wall_lvl_1_1 = pygame.Rect(0,225,250,50)
wall_lvl_1_2 = pygame.Rect(300,250,200,50)
border1_lvl_1 = pygame.Rect(0,0,25,500)
border2_lvl_1 = pygame.Rect(0,0,500,25)
border3_lvl_1 = pygame.Rect(0,0,1,1)
pygame.draw.rect(windowSurface,white,wall_lvl_1_1)
render()

while True:
    render()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                direction = 'left'
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                direction = 'right'
            if event.key == K_UP:
                direction = 'up'
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                direction = 'down'
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    if player1.colliderect(wall_lvl_1_1) or player1.colliderect(wall_lvl_1_2):
        xmod = 0
        ymod = 0
        player1 = pygame.Rect(225 + xmod,450 - ymod,30,30)
        print('again')
    if direction == 'left':
        xmod -= 1
        sleep(0.004)
    if direction == 'right':
        xmod += 1
        sleep(0.004)
    if direction == 'up':
        ymod += 1
        sleep(0.004)
    if direction == 'down':
        ymod -= 1
        sleep(0.004)
    if ymod == 450:
        level = 2
    render()
```

Comment: I have looked this up but i didnt find anything on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the position of the `player1` rect each frame.

```
player1.topleft = (xmod, ymod)
```

Comment: Also, up and down are swapped.